# scanbd unable to detect scanner

Tags: raspberry-pi, sane

I am trying to setup a scan station using my Canon CanoScan LiDE 110 connected to a pi zero w running DietPi 8.1.2.
Initially I had `saned` running and it worked fine.

`scanimage -L` listed my scanner and I was able to scan from a networked system using xsane.

I decided to try to use `scanbd` to make scanning easier with the buttons on the scanner.

following docs [here](https://sodocumentation.net/raspberry-pi/topic/6701/create-a-scan-station-with-scanbd--raspbian-) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Scanner_Button_Daemon)

I installed the scanbd package,

copied the original config to /etc/scanbd/sane.d

```
root@cscan:/etc/scanbd/sane.d# egrep -v '^#|^$' {dll,net}.conf
dll.conf:genesys
```

Created a symlink for good measure

```
root@cscan:/var/log# ls -la /usr/local/etc/scanbd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Feb  7 08:53 /usr/local/etc/scanbd -> /etc/scanbd/
```

modified the existing saned config to point to net only and localhost, so that it wouldn't try to connect directly to the scanner,

```
root@cscan:/etc/sane.d# egrep -v '^#|^$' {net,dll}.conf
net.conf: connect_timeout = 3
net.conf: localhost
dll.conf:net
```

enable and start systemd stuff

```
root@cscan:/var/log# systemctl status {scanbd,scanbm.socket}
? scanbd.service - Scanner button polling Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/scanbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-07 08:53:41 EST; 36min ago
 Main PID: 2438 (scanbd)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 991)
   CGroup: /system.slice/scanbd.service
           ??2438 /usr/sbin/scanbd -f -c /etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf

Feb 07 08:53:41 cscan systemd[1]: Started Scanner button polling Service.
Feb 07 08:53:41 cscan scanbd[2438]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='or
g.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
Feb 07 08:57:59 cscan scanbd[2438]: /usr/sbin/scanbd: trigger action for scan for device gen
esys:libusb:001:003 with script test.script
Feb 07 08:58:00 cscan scanbd[2475]: /usr/share/scanbd/scripts/test.script: Begin of scan for
 device genesys:libusb:001:003
Feb 07 08:58:00 cscan scanbd[2478]: /usr/share/scanbd/scripts/test.script: End   of scan for
 device genesys:libusb:001:003

? scanbm.socket - scanbd/saned incoming socket
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/scanbm.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Mon 2022-02-07 08:53:49 EST; 36min ago
   Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
 Accepted: 5; Connected: 0;
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 991)
   CGroup: /system.slice/scanbm.socket

Feb 07 08:53:49 cscan systemd[1]: Listening on scanbd/saned incoming socket.
```

It appears that the scan button is launching the test.script as expected (see above)
but scanbd -f doesn't seem to connect to my scanner.

```
root@cscan:/etc/scanbd# scanbd -d7 -f
scanbd: foreground
scanbd: reading config file /etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf
scanbd: debug on: level: 7
scanbd: dropping privs to uid saned
scanbd: dropping privs to gid scanner
scanbd: group scanner has member:
scanbd: saned
scanbd: drop privileges to gid: 115
scanbd: Running as effective gid 115
scanbd: drop privileges to uid: 108
scanbd: Running as effective uid 108
scanbd: dbus_init
scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
scanbd: SANE_CONFIG_DIR not set
scanbd: sane version 1.0
scanbd: Scanning for local-only devices
scanbd: start_sane_threads
scanbd: no devices, not starting any polling thread
scanbd: start dbus thread
scanbd: Not Primary Owner (2)
scanbd: udev init
scanbd: get udev monitor
scanbd: udev fd is non-blocking, now setting to blocking mode
scanbd: start udev thread
scanbd: timeout: 500 ms
scanbd: Iteration on dbus call
scanbd: udev thread started
scanbd: Iteration on dbus call
```

SANE_CONFIG_DIR variable appears to be defined in scanbd.conf

```
root@cscan:/etc/scanbd# grep -r SANE_CONFIG_DIR
scanbd.conf:            saned_env  = { "SANE_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/scanbd" } # list of environment vars for saned
```

And, scanimage -L does work locally, but not remotely

```
root@cscan:~# scanimage -L
device `net:localhost:genesys:libusb:001:002' is a Canon LiDE 110 flatbed scanner

user@desktop:/etc/sane.d $ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

At this point I have run out of ideas.  Is there anyone out there who can help me out with this?  My ultimate goal is to be able to network scan via `saned` using xsane and saneTwain, and use the front panel buttons to do script magic.

Comment: I fixed something :)

`cp /etc/sane.d/saned.conf /etc/scanbd/`


`root@rvscan:~# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/scanbd/saned.conf
192.168.17.1/24`

now I can scan from remote desktop using xsane

Comment: I've gotten one of the scan buttons to work.  It scans to tiff/jpg in /var/spool/scan now.  I had to adjust perms on that directory for the scanner group to have write.